# How to change the a Header of HttpContent

Tags: c#, httpclient

I have this code to change the Header of my content from `{text/plain; charset=utf-8}` to `"{application/json}"`

```
using (System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
{
    string content = "some json data";
    System.Net.Http.StringContent sc = new System.Net.Http.StringContent(content);
    sc.Headers.Remove("Content-Type"); // "{text/plain; charset=utf-8}"
    sc.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
    System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync("http://foo.bar", sc).Result;
}
```

Is there a way to modify it directly instead of removin and adding it?

Comment: Quick question - how do you get `"some json data"`? You have it as string, or you create string manually by serializing some data?

Comment: could you not use [PostAsJsonAsync()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclientextensions.postasjsonasync(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Net.Http.HttpClientExtensions.PostAsJsonAsync``1(System.Net.Http.HttpClient,System.String,``0) instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this overload of `StringContent` for setting **content-type**

```
sc = new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

After this, you don't need to add/remove header values.

Answer (score 1):

If you are building json string manuallly by serializing some data, then there is much better way. You can use [`PostAsJsonAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclientextensions.postasjsonasync(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Net.Http.HttpClientExtensions.PostAsJsonAsync%60%601(System.Net.Http.HttpClient,System.String,%60%600)) extension method:

```
using (System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
{
    var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("http://foo.bar", data);
}
```

It will automatically do following things

- Serialize data to JSON
- Create StringContent
- Provide correct application/json media type